# How to run a Maven plugin execution only if the resulting output is not already present

Tags: maven

I have inherited a POM that attempts to avoid repeating build steps by using a profile
that is only activated when the step output does not exist:

```
<profile>
 <id>run-once</id>
  <activation>
    <file>
     <missing>target/some-output</missing>
    </file>
  </activation>
  <build>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     ...
     <executions>
      <execution>
       ... slow process to produce target/some-output ...
      </execution>
     </executions>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
 </activation>
```

However, as maven experts no doubt realized immediately, this does not work if the developer says `mvn clean install`.  Maven calculates the active profiles once, before running `clean`, and if `target/some-output` was present, then the `run-once` profile is not active.  The result is that `target/some-output` is removed by the clean phase but is not recreated in the `install` phase, and the ensuing WAR is broken because `some-output` is missing.

Is there a standard solution to this problem (besides avoiding `mvn clean install`) ?  I'm about to make the plugin unconditional to prevent the silent creation of a broken WAR.

More generally, is there a standard technique to prevent mvn from recreating artifacts like `some-output` that are up-to-date?  Or is the idea that if make-style dependency management is important, one should use gradle or rake instead of maven?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? compiling? resources? Why using `mvn clean install` and not `mvn clean package` or may be `mvn package`? Why build steps would you like to prevent repeating ? Mutli Module build?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Because it is possible to make source-compatible but binary-incompatible changes to a Java class, the only way to ensure that all .class files are consistent is to clean and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard solution to this problem. There are though various options that I can think of (there are most likely others as well):

- you could obviously activate the profile manually: `mvn clean install -Prun-once`, but then you have to remember to do that each time of course
- configure the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) together with its [requireFilesExist](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html) rule to make sure the files exist and fail the build if they don't. (at least then you wont get the silent creation of a broken WAR)
- modify the profile to have it create the files to a location under your `src` folder (i.e. `src/main/gen`) which is excluded from being checked into your source repository (if you are using one), and then configure the [maven-resources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/) and its [copy-resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html) goal to copy these resources to the correct location under your build directory. This way clean wont delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  IMO it's antithetical to the entire concept of 'clean' if artifacts created by the build are not removed by clean.